# Having trouble with JWT token in ASP.NET Core app with multiple authentication schemes

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, jwt

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.0 app with both web pages and API. I'm using cookie authentication for web pages and now I want to use `JWT Tokens` for API methods.

I followed this article to set this up which does a pretty good job in walking us through the process: https://wildermuth.com/2017/08/19/Two-AuthorizationSchemes-in-ASP-NET-Core-2

I am, however, getting a strange response in my API method that I set up to use `JWT token`. When I hit the API method, I do get a `Status 200` response in Postman but I never hit the break point I set up in the API method. More interestingly, Visual Studio debugger is showing a successful request and when I click it, I see a response code `302` even though Postman shows me a `200` -- see below:
[image]

Stranger still, the response I see in Postman is the HTML code of my login page which I redirect users to if they're not authenticated.

Here's my configuration for authentication. As you'll see below, I use social logins as well so my configuration is a bit long so I put all the configuration in a separate file in order not to clutter my `Startup.cs`. I simply call this from the `ConfigureServices()` method.

```
public static void MyAppAuthenticationConfig(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
     services.AddAuthentication(options =>
     {
         options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "my_cookie";
         options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "my_cookie";
     })
     .AddCookie("my_cookie", options =>
     {
         options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Home/Denied";
         options.LoginPath = "/Login";
     })
     .AddCookie("social_auth_cookie")
     .AddOAuth("LinkedIn", options =>
     {
         options.SignInScheme = "social_auth_cookie";

         options.ClientId = "my_client_id";
         options.ClientSecret = "my_secret";

         options.CallbackPath = "/linkedin-callback";

         options.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization";
         options.TokenEndpoint = "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken";
         options.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,email-address,picture-url,picture-urls::(original))";

         options.Scope.Add("r_basicprofile");
         options.Scope.Add("r_emailaddress");

         options.Events = new OAuthEvents
         {
             OnCreatingTicket = OnCreatingTicketLinkedInCallBack,
             OnTicketReceived = OnTicketReceivedCallback
         };
      })
      .AddFacebook(options =>
      {
          options.SignInScheme = "social_auth_cookie";
          options.AppId = "my_app_id";
          options.AppSecret = "my_secret";
          options.Events = new OAuthEvents
          {
              OnCreatingTicket = OnCreatingTicketFacebookCallback,
              OnTicketReceived = OnTicketReceivedCallback
          };
      })
      .AddGoogle(options =>
      {
          options.SignInScheme = "social_auth_cookie";
          options.ClientId = "my_id.apps.googleusercontent.com";
          options.ClientSecret = "my_secret";
          options.CallbackPath = "/google-callback";
          options.Events = new OAuthEvents
          {
              OnCreatingTicket = OnCreatingTicketGoogleCallback,
              OnTicketReceived = OnTicketReceivedCallback
          };
       })
       .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, jwtBearerOptions =>
       {
           jwtBearerOptions.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
           jwtBearerOptions.SaveToken = true;
           jwtBearerOptions.Challenge = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
           jwtBearerOptions.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
           {
               ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
               IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("my_secret_key")),
               ValidateIssuer = true,
               ValidIssuer = "myapp-api",
               ValidateAudience = true,
               ValidAudience = "myapp-client",
               ValidateLifetime = true,

               ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)
           };
       });
}
```

And this is the API method where I want to use `JWT Token`.

```
[HttpGet("testit")]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public IActionResult Test()
{
    return Ok("Hello World!");
}
```

I have a break point where I `return Ok("Hello World!");` but like I said I never hit it.

What am I doing wrong here?

UPDATE:
When I inspect the `ChallangeResult("Bearer")`, this is what I see:
[image]

And here's how I'm sending my request in Postman:
[image]

Comment: Do you have `[Authorize]` setup on the controller?

Comment: I have `app.UseAuthentication();` in `Configure()` method in `Startup.cs` so I don't have anything specified at the controller level. If try to hit a method in the controller anonymously though, I do get rejected.

Comment: Does it hit Test() if you replace Authorize with Anonymous?

Comment: Yes. If I decorate the API method with `[AllowAnonymous]`, I do hit my break point.

Comment: Could you try the following: Set [Anonymous] and set inside Test() the following: `if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) return new ChallengeResult("Bearer");` 1) can you see that the user is authenticated? 2) Does this change the result?

Comment: Looks like my code is not getting the bearer token. The result I get is `401 Unauthorized`. If I put a break point where I get the `ChallangeResult`, and inspect what's in it, I don't see a token -- see the screen shot I posted to original post.

Comment: I also posted a picture of how I'm sending the token in Postman.

Comment: Perhaps the token isn't accepted because you didn't set jwtBearerOptions.Authority in .AddJwtBearer. Does it make a difference if you add it?

Comment: I just tried something that is interesting. As you can see in the code above, I was not doing anything about capturing the token and extracting the claims out of it. I thought this would be done automatically. I just added an event for `OnTokenValidated` and looks like I'm hitting that with the claims in it. I guess I need to handle that part manually.

Comment: Not working at all. I must be making a fundamental error somewhere. If I roll back to adding the `[Authorize]` attribute in my controller action, I get the same results. I'm not even hitting the `AddJwtBearer` code to inspect the token. I'm sending the token in the header using Postman. If I hit the controller method which is decorated with `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]`, shouldn't I at the very least hit the `AddJwtBearer` section to resolve the token?

Comment: Can you include the relevant part of the log?